Word prints a non-filled square filled as solid black
My colleagues shared a Microsoft Word file. It contains a square (without fill) with some text in it.
Computer A prints it out without any problem.
Computer B prints the square filled black (see picture).
Same file, printer, and driver. Is there any setting wrong in computer B?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

suspect: The Gfx-driver on the affected computer has a bug, check for updates, reinstall or replace by any alternative.

@Hannu
Thanks, I really don't know graphic driver will caused such problems, will test at Monday
